# Can't compile Arduino sketch on MacOSX

Tags: java, macos, compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm having troubles compiling a simple sketch on Mac, I'm using Mojave versión and I have Arduino IDE 1.8.7.

Once I click on check or upload It gets freezed on "Compiling Sketch". I have tried to ran like sudo and nothing happen.

Here are my logs, I'm using Java 1.8 has default. Hope you can help me.

Thank you!

```
[JmDNS(fe80-0-0-0-aede-48ff-fe00-1122-en5.local.).State.Timer] WARN javax.jmdns.impl.tasks.state.DNSStateTask - Canceler(fe80-0-0-0-aede-48ff-fe00-1122-en5.local.).run() exception 
java.io.IOException: No route to host (sendto failed)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl.send(JmDNSImpl.java:1618)
    at javax.jmdns.impl.tasks.state.DNSStateTask.run(DNSStateTask.java:131)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[fe80-0-0-0-1865-b6b4-2043-2516-en0.local..recover()] WARN javax.jmdns.impl.DNSStatefulObject$DefaultImplementation - Wait for canceled timed out: DNS: fe80-0-0-0-1865-b6b4-2043-2516-en0.local. [fe80:0:0:0:1865:b6b4:2043:2516%en0/fe80:0:0:0:1865:b6b4:2043:2516%en0] state: canceling 1 task: null
[fe80-0-0-0-1865-b6b4-2043-2516-en0.local..recover()] WARN javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl - fe80-0-0-0-1865-b6b4-2043-2516-en0.local..recover() Could not recover we are Down!
[fe80-0-0-0-aede-48ff-fe00-1122-en5.local..recover()] WARN javax.jmdns.impl.DNSStatefulObject$DefaultImplementation - Wait for canceled timed out: DNS: fe80-0-0-0-aede-48ff-fe00-1122-en5.local. [fe80:0:0:0:aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5/fe80:0:0:0:aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5] state: canceling 1 task: null
[fe80-0-0-0-aede-48ff-fe00-1122-en5.local..recover()] WARN javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl - fe80-0-0-0-aede-48ff-fe00-1122-en5.local..recover() Could not recover we are Down!


/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/zreactor/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0043 -ide-version=10807 -build-path /var/folders/_b/8334gfj95qq4lk91rv1yl_3h0000gn/T/arduino_build_939925 -warnings=all -build-cache /var/folders/_b/8334gfj95qq4lk91rv1yl_3h0000gn/T/arduino_cache_484968 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -verbose /Users/zreactor/Projects/arduino/keypad_led/keypad_led.ino
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/zreactor/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0X2341_0X0043 -ide-version=10807 -build-path /var/folders/_b/8334gfj95qq4lk91rv1yl_3h0000gn/T/arduino_build_939925 -warnings=all -build-cache /var/folders/_b/8334gfj95qq4lk91rv1yl_3h0000gn/T/arduino_cache_484968 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino14.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.2.1.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-5.4.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino2.path=/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -verbose /Users/zreactor/Projects/arduino/keypad_led/keypad_led.ino
Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr
Detecting libraries used...
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10807 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard /var/folders/_b/8334gfj95qq4lk91rv1yl_3h0000gn/T/arduino_build_939925/sketch/keypad_led.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
```